# Why is it entering the first if statement although the variable is smaller?

Tags: javascript

This is a very simple code part which simply doesn't work.

I'm trying to compare 2 arrays - if `a_arr[i]` > than `b_arr[i]` add points to `a` else add points to `b`.

and i keep getting the code running into the first if statement although `b_arr[i]` has a bigger value.

```
function solve(a_arr, b_arr){

    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;

    for (var i = 0, len = 3; i < len; i++) {

        if (a_arr[i] == b_arr[i]) {

        } else {

            if (a_arr[i] > b_arr[i]){
                a++;
            } else {
                b++;
            }

        }

    }

    var result = [a, b];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: please provide an example of the 2 arrays you are having problems with

Comment: `[6, 7, 8]` and `[4, 7, 11]` should result `[1, 1]`, and currently resulting `[2, 0]`

Comment: @RickSanchez no, its returning `[1.1]` itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of your exact code as a snippet. As you can see, `a` increased 1 times and `b` increased 1 time. Your code works fine. I think you have a problem examining your results.

```js
function solve(a_arr, b_arr){

    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;

    for (var i = 0, len = 3; i < len; i++) {

        if (a_arr[i] == b_arr[i]) {

        } else {

            if (a_arr[i] > b_arr[i]){
                a++;
            } else {
                b++;
            }

        }

    }

    var result = [a, b];
    return result;
}

arr1 = [6,7,8];
arr2 = [4,7,11];

arr3 = solve(arr1, arr2);
console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: You should vote to close as "cannot reproduce" then.

Comment: @Bergi I did. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. However it isnt bulletproof. A static *len* can cause some problems with different sized arrays. May do:

```
 function solve(a_arr, b_arr){
   var a = 0,b = 0;
   for (var i = 0, len = Math.min(a_arr.length,b_arr.length); i < len; i++) {
    if (a_arr[i] == b_arr[i]) continue;
    if (a_arr[i] > b_arr[i]){
      a++;
    } else {
      b++;
    }
   }
  return [a,b];
 }
```